# How could I close VsCode's Collapsible Block Comments"

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open a new file, VsCode generally expands everything by default. When there is a large amount of code in a single file, I usually use ctrl+k, ctrl+ number to quickly collapse the specified level.

I love this feature, but it always collapses jsDoc comments, aka block comments or multiline comments.This makes the code unreadable, since a big part of the comment is for me to read.

For example：

VsCode's existing folding effects:
[image]
When I fold the code with ctrl+k, ctrl+ number, the jsDoc comment is folded like this.

The effect I want:
[image]

I want the comment code never to be folded when I fold the code.

All the articles on Google talk about folding comments, but I don't want to fold comments.
How can VsCode be set up so that it does not collapse multiple lines of comment code? Or it can be solved by a plug-in.

I did a lot of searches on Google and they all talked about how to fold comments, using //region to create a custom fold area, different from my question.

In VsCode, I found the "Collapse all block comments" shortcut, but not the "expand all block comments" shortcut